# Java: Openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.docPropsVTypes.CTArray not found

Tags: java, compiler-errors, apache-poi

When I try to compile my project, I get a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.docPropsVTypes.CTArray not found`-error. I've read that this has something to do with the openxml jar.
I'm using Apache POI, I've downloaded POI-4.1.0.rar and added this to my Netbeans libraries. This rar contains a poi-ooxml-schemas.jar, which I assume is causing the error. However I'm not sure if this is what causing the error, or if I'm missing a jar.

This is an overview of the libraries in my project.
[image: Jars]

Comment: Did you [try following the advice in the Apache POI FAQ on the topic](http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having same exact exception you described. I followed this advise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38262782/4101334

Second part of Finbarr O'B response has fix description.
This part also important: "Be sure to remove the poi-ooxml-schemas dependency from your maven pom.xml so that ooxml-schemas above takes precedence instead."